# how to know if a button is enabled using selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am trying to know whether a button is enabled or disabled so i can click on it.
I have tried this code but it seems of no use:

```
button = browser.find_elements_by_id("join_button_input")[0].click()
            print(button)
            if button == None:
                k = 1
                while (k<=10):
                    time.sleep(10)
                    browser.refresh()
                    button
                    k+=1
```

Here is the html text that I am using:

```
<input id="join_button_input" type="button" value="Join session" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="M.mod_bigbluebuttonbn.rooms.join('http://live.webcentreindia.com/mod/bigbluebuttonbn/bbb_view.php?action=join&id=893&bn=890');" disabled="true">
```

Comment: You can check the attribute value by `.find_elements_by_id("join_button_input")[0].get_attribute('disabled')`

Comment: @frianH Of course, there can only be one button with a given id. so: `.find_element_by_id("join_button_input").click()`

Comment: @Booboo yes right, id should unique in the HTML page. But refers to OP, the user using `.find_elements` not `.find_element`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an answer refers to the comment with a bit explanation.

You can check the attribute value by `.get_attribute('disabled')` method.

And I think you should use `.find_element*` (without `s`) not `.find_elements*`, because find by `id` is unique:

```
disable_val = driver.find_element_by_id('join_button_input').get_attribute('disabled')
if disable_val == 'true':
    #perform
    ....
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

`BeautifulSoup` won't help here because the page uses javascript to render the text (`selenium` will help though). Or you can use `re`/`json` module to extract the data:

```
import re
import json
import requests

ExampleSite = "https://throwbin.io/liWq2S3"
html_doc = requests.get(ExampleSite).text

d = re.search(r'}\((.*?)\)\);', html_doc).group(1)
d = json.loads('[' + d + ']')

print('Title:', d[4])
print('-' * 80)
print(d[5])
```

Prints:

```
Title: Soup
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Apple
Orange
Cake
Pizza
```